# How to use a mongoose model defined in a separate file if the file is not exported?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider a very simple Express 4 app structure:

```
-- app.js
-- models
     |--db.js
     |--news.js
```

where `news.js` contains a mongoose schema and a model based on that schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var newsSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    // other fields...
});

var News = mongoose.model('News', newsSchema);
```

To my understanding, in order for `app.js` to use the `News` model, it has to require the file within the script like this: `require('./models/news')`. Also, `news.js` would have to export the model like this: `module.exports = News;`.

However, I have come across a number of scripts that do not export models (or anything for that matter) defined in a separate file while still be able to use those models and/or schema in a different file just by requiring the model file and then do something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var News = mongoose.model('News');
```

How is this behavior possible? It is a special feature of Mongoose? How can a file use a model or schema defined in another file if that model/schema is not exported within that file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ultimately works because when you call `require('mongoose')` in various files, you get back the same object. In other words: it gets shared between `app.js` and `news.js`, in your case.

When you create a new model (using `mongoose.Model('Name', schema)`), Mongoose stores that model instance in an internal list of models.

This also allows you to get an instance by name, using `mongoose.Model('Name')`. Mongoose will look up that model in its internal list, and return it.

Comment: Hi Robert! Thank you for your reply! So the `mongoose` instance returned by calling `require('mongoose')` is a singleton? Therefore as soon as a model is registered, it becomes a part of the `mongoose` singleton. As long as the connection remains the same, calling `mongoose` from any script of the app would grant me access to the defined models. Is that right?

Comment: It makes sense to me now. However does the same behavior extend to Schema as well? If I define a schema in one script and do not export it, will other scripts that call `require('mongoose')` have access to the schema? Or is that behavior limited to models only, but not schema?

Comment: @ArenLi yes, it's basically a singleton. The same doesn't apply to schema, only models. I think that's because schema are regarded as being "private": they aren't of use besides creating models with (for instance, once you created a model from a schema, you can't change the schema for the model).